# How can I tell whether it's safe/necessary to cudaFree() or not?

Tags: memory-management, cuda, free

I've allocated some GPU global memory with `cudaMalloc()`, say, in the constructor of some class. Now it's time to destruct the instance I've constructed, and I have my instance's data pointer. The thing is, I'm worried maybe some mischievous code elsewhere has called `cudaDeviceReset()`, after which my `cudaFree()` will probably fail (I'll get an `invalid device pointer` error). So, how can can I tell whether my pointer is elligible for `cudaFree()`ing?

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you can do much about that.

About the best you can do is try and engineer the lifespan of objects which will call the CUDA APIs in their destructors to do so before context destruction. In practice, that means having them fall of of scope in a well defined fashion before the context is automatically or manually torn down.

For a call like `cudaFree()`, which is somewhat "fire and forget" anyway, the best thing to do might be to write your own wrapper for the call and explicitly catch and tastefully ignore any obvious error conditions which would arise if the call was made after context destruction-

Comment: What about other potential causes for the "invalid pointer" error? Are there? If not, I can indeed safely ignore the failure.

Answer (score 2):

Given what talonmies [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34158214/1593077), one might consider doing the converse:

- wrap your `cudaDeviceReset()` calls to also regard a 'generation counter'.
- Counter increases will be protected by a lock.
- While you lock, you reset and increment the generation counter.
- Wrap `cudaMalloc()` to also keep the generation index (you might need a class/struct for that) - obtained during allocation (which also locks).
- Wrap `cudaFree()` to lock and only really `cudaFree()` if the reset generation has not changed.

... now, you might say "Is all that locking worth it? At worst, you'll get an error, it's not such a big deal." And, to be honest - I'm not sure it's worth it. You could make this somewhat less painful by using  a [Reader-Writer lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) instead of a simple lock, where the allocate and free are just readers that can all access concurrently.